# Retrieve destination IP of a packet that has been NATed to a docker container connected to a docker bridge network?

Tags: docker, networking

Is it possible to retrieve the destination IP of a packet that has been forwarded to a container via a docker bridge network? Is it logged somewhere, or is it possible to enable some logging to have that info?

My setup is the following: I have a container that uses several IP addresses on a host. Its network is in default mode, i.e. connected to a bridge network. This means (correct me if I'm wrong) that when a packet is sent to one of the container's IP, it is actually received by the docker daemon, that then forwards it to the container, using the container's internal address on the bridge network. The container is hence unaware of the real destination address, and has no way of knowing as far as I know. Is the NATing logged somewhere? Or is there any way to retrieve that information?

Comment: A bridge or switch is a transparent device that switches frames based on the layer-2, e.g. MAC, address, and it is unaware of the layer-3, e.g. IP, protocol used. Layer-2 frames can contain any layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.) and the bridge can switch them because it doesn't know or care about the frame payload. A bridge does not NAT because it is unaware of the layer-3 protocol, of which only IPv4 can use NAT.

Comment: Hum you're right obviously; I guess that the docker concept of "network" consists of both the layer-2 bridge and the associated iptables rules; i.e. if I do a `docker network inspect xxx` I'll see both the definition of the bridge network, and the configuration enabling IP NATing. I'll try to edit my answer to make it clearer